# Do not allow comma or point on input text

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, validation, prototype-js

How could I validate only integer numbers on input text Magento?

The file I need to change in text.phtml and I know all of the validation terms on prototype, so I just need to know how to insert this on the code.

Comment: You can use `isNaN` to validate if the entered input is number of not. You can wrap it up in function and call it using some class by jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 4):

Add a class called "validate-digits" to your input type text line in the form.bascially it will look like

```
<input type="text" class="(your_other_classes) validate-digits" />
```

for more validation classes you can refer [Form Validation in Magento](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

Note : 
***'validate-digits' => 'Please use numbers only in this field. Please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas.'***